# Not Able to register a user with Hyperledger-Fabric v1.1 preview

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hi I am not able to register a user with fabric v1.1 preview I am using node-sdk balance transfer example
This is the error log

```
2017/12/19 10:15:43 [DEBUG] Received request for /api/v1/register
2017/12/19 10:15:43 [DEBUG] Checking for revocation/expiration of certificate owned by 'admin'
2017/12/19 10:15:43 [DEBUG] DB: Get certificate by serial (2579edfb30a98bc8200916a7898f0de00280865) and aki (e729224e8b3f31784c8a93c5b8ef6f4c1c91d9e6e577c45c33163609fe40011)
2017/12/19 10:15:43 [DEBUG] Received registration request from : { Name:Jim456 Type: Secret:**** MaxEnrollments:1 Affiliation:org1.department1 Attributes:[{Role  false}] CAName:ca-org1  }
2017/12/19 10:15:43 [DEBUG] Sent error for /api/v1/register: scode: 401, local code: 30, local msg: Certificate not found with AKI 'e729224e8b3f31784c8a93c5b8ef6f4c1c91d9e6e577c45c33163609fe40011' and serial '2579edfb30a98bc8200916a7898f0de00280865', remote code: 20, remote msg: Authorization failure

github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.newAuthErr
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/servererror.go:145
github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.(*serverRequestContext).TokenAuthentication
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/serverrequestcontext.go:157
github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.registerHandler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/serverregister.go:49
github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib.(*serverEndpoint).ServeHTTP
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/serverendpoint.go:44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP
    /opt/go/src/net/http/server.go:2254
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP
    /opt/go/src/net/http/server.go:2619
net/http.(*conn).serve
    /opt/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337
2017/12/19 10:15:43 [INFO] 172.19.0.1:56246 POST /api/v1/register 401 30 "Certificate not found with AKI 'e729224e8b3f31784c8a93c5b8ef6f4c1c91d9e6e577c45c33163609fe40011' and serial '2579edfb30a98bc8200916a7898f0de00280865'"
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct affiliation while registration? Can you post the full CA log since start?

Answer (score 3):

The error:

> "Certificate not found with AKI 'e729224e8b3f31784c8a93c5b8ef6f4c1c91d9e6e577c45c33163609fe40011' and serial '2579edfb30a98bc8200916a7898f0de00280865', remote code: 20, remote msg: Authorization failure"

Suggests that the CA didn't find the certificate that you gave it (from the admin).

If you are enrolling the admin with the CA to get fresh certificates this should solve your issue.

It seems that you may be using old certificates stored in your KVS store file that pertains to the prior network. This problem is simply caused by you restarting a fresh network and keeping the prior KVS, thus when you run your code, it checks if the user is stored and uses those credentials instead of getting new ones. Always remember to delete your kvs when restarting your network.